# Where is the shape feature with loop subdivision

Tags: cgal

Is there shape feature with loop subdivision or others subdivision algorithms in the CGAL? Thank you so much！

Answer (score 0):

It's not there because there is a patent by Pixar on it. If you need sharp features, you can use the [OpenSubdiv](http://graphics.pixar.com/opensubdiv/docs/intro.html) library from Pixar that includes sharp feature handling without the patent restriction IIRC.